# How to generate a rating meta tag in TYPO3 with caching?

Tags: typo3, typo3-extensions

I would like to generate a rich snippet for ratings in my TYPO3 pages. The rating information are fetched via an API, so I need some kind of caching mechanism.

I have some basic knowledge and experience with TYPO3 extensions, but I am not sure about the cleanest solution. I could render the meta tags with the TYPO3 Meta Tag API and cache the fetched information using the TYPO3 Caching Framework.

But I am not sure where to store the logic so that it gets executed at every page visit. I do not want to use a content plugin for obvious reasons. Should I set up a Controller and call the Contoller's function with e.g. some hook?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Which version of TYPO3 are you using ?

Comment: @StatiX Currently still V8 LTS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have a look at the `tslib/class.tslib_fe.php` hooks in `TypoScriptFrontendController` class.

Choose the correct one (maybe `tslib_fe-PostProc`) and do something like this :

1) Register hook in `ext_localconf.php`

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['tslib/class.tslib_fe.php']['tslib_fe-PostProc'][] = \Vendor\Name\Hook\AdditionalMetaData::class . '->addRating';
```

2) Create your class with the following method

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Name\Hook;

class AdditionalMetaData
{
    /**
     * @param array $parameters
     * @return void
     */
    public function addRating(&$parameters)
    {
        /** @var TypoScriptFrontendController $tsfe */
        $tsfe = &$parameters['pObj'];
        // Do your logic here...
    }
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you! If anybody wants to use this solution in the future, please note 2 things: 1) the class path needs to be added to the autoload section in composer.json, 2) the hook `tslib_fe-PostProc` is deprecated since Typo3 v9.5 in favour to middleware solutions.